# Oracle APEX 5 Create Function ERROR, what could it be?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5

Oracle Apex 5 SQL commands gives this error when I try to run the below function code : ‘ORA-24344: success with compilation error’

I've tried writing it in all caps and still the issues appears. What do you think I did wrong? Help would be really appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION al_auth_authentication (p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN boolean
    IS
    1_user AL_USER_LOGIN.USER_NAME%type := UPPER(p_username);
    1_pwd  AL_USER_LOGIN.USER_PASSWORD%type;
    1_id   AL_USER_LOGIN.USER_ID%type;
    BEGIN
    SELECT USER_ID, USER_PASSWORD
    INTO 1_id, 1_pwd
    FROM AL_USER_LOGIN
    WHERE UPPER(USER_NAME) = 1_user;
    RETURN 1_pwd = dbms_crypto.hash (UTL_I18N.string_to_raw(p_password || 1_id || UPPER(p_username), 'AL32UTF8'), dbms_crypto.hash_sh1);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found then return false;
    END al_auth_authentication;
```

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL variables (and [Oracle identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm) in general) can't begin with a number, so `1_user`, `1_pwd` and `1_id` are not valid. Perhaps you meant `l_user`, `l_pwd` and `l_id`?

You should include the full compilation error in your question, though. You can either compile it in a development tool that highlights compilation errors, such as [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) or [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html), or in [SQL*Plus](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/sqlplus-setup.html) and use the `show errors` command, or else just query `user_errors` (or `all_errors` if you are not connected as the owner).

There is no need to code in block capitals unless you are working in COBOL, so please don't.

Comment: Hi, thank you. However, changing the name of the variable has had no effect and still brings the same error. I'm not sure about full compilation error, I just got this 'PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" ' and 'PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "1"... ' I fixed the 1 though

Comment: You can either compile it in a development tool that highlights compilation errors or else query user_errors (or all_errors if you are not connected as the owner). btw there are three variables beginning with `1_` (i.e. the digit 'one'). Perhaps you meant `l_` (the letter 'L').

Comment: It also says' PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_CRYPTO' must be declared'

Comment: My overall aim is to create authentication username and password. However, I want to hash the password and compare it to my table of "passwords"

Comment: @AbdirizakObsiye: you'll need to grant execute privileges on the `DBMS_CRYPTO` package to the user you're creating the function as.  (I just tried creating your function in Oracle 11g XE and I got that error too.)

Comment: The [documentation for dbms_crypto](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_crypto.htm) says under Security Model: _"Oracle Database installs this package in the SYS schema. You can then grant package access to existing users and roles as needed."_

Comment: Thank you, I believe it's a privelege issue. How do I grant myself execute priveleges for dbms_crypto?

Comment: @LukeWoodward above comment

Comment: As either the SYS user or a user with the DBA role, [`grant`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm) `execute on sys.dbms_crypto to someuser` (substitute the owner of your function for 'someuser'').

Comment: @WilliamRobertson an error appears 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist' it's frustrating. I wrote 'grant execute on sys.dbms_crypto to [my schema name]'

Comment: Sounds like the grant solved the problem accessing dbms_crypto, and you are now looking at the next compilation error, which is about a table that it can't see. Looks like the only table your function uses is AL_USER_LOGIN. Is it present in the same schema as your function?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I wrote grant execute on sys.dbms_crypto to someuser; and clicked run then it said table or view does not exist. I think it thinks sys is a table.

Comment: Were you connected as sys or a user with the DBA role? Or maybe the package isn't installed. Query dba_objects to check. Or talk to your DBA if there is one. We might be drifting off topic though - SO isn't generally keen on long comment thread conversations.